# Roslyn: Can not get ms visual studio 2008 project files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, roslyn

Is it possible to load ms visual studio 2008 project files via roslyn apis? In the below code snippet, assuming projectFilePath contains the path to the .csproj file, the docs collection is empty when the project is ms visual studio 2008 project (Although files DO exist in the project).

```
  IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject(projectFilePath);
  var project = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.First();
  var docs = project.Documents;
```

However, when I convert the solution with ms visual studio 2012, the same code returns the documents in the project.

Does this mean that roslyn workspace apis are NOT interoperable with visual studio 2008?

If that is so, is there any workaround to get/iterate over visual studio 2008 project files?

P.S: I have very little experience with c# and roslyn so please forgive me for any naive statements!!!:)

Comment: Are you able to post the .csproj file somewhere? I don't need any of the actual source files. This might just be a bug...

Comment: Hi jason, I have uploaded 2 sample project files to : http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3bfe781a4af739c69993740135cfa5175a4fe3b9c  . I would be very grateful if you could comment. We have hundreds of projects to be processed by Roslyn. Unfortunately none of the projects is vs2012.

Comment: Anyone have a comment????